# Unexpected ',' when using lines function in R

Tags: r, probability

I am trying to plot multiple distributions on the same plot using the lines function but I am getting an error. The error reads:

*Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): :8:16: unexpected ',' 

8: lines <- (xvals,*

```
xvals <- seq(-5, 10,, length.out=501)  

pdf1 <- pnorm(xvals, mean=0, sd=1)
plot(xvals, pdf1, type='l', xlab='x', ylab='f(x)', main='PDF of N(0,1), N(2,2^2) and N(-1,0.5^2)')

pdf2 <- pnorm(xvals, mean=2, sd=sqrt(2))
pdf3 <- pnorm(xvals, mean=-1, sd=sqrt(0.5))


lines <- (xvals, pdf2, col = 'red')
lines <- (xvals, pdf3, col = 'blue')
```

Comment: You have an extra comma in your `xvals` definition. Change `10,,` to `10,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```r
xvals <- seq(-5, 10, length.out=501)  

pdf1 <- pnorm(xvals, mean=0, sd=1)
plot(xvals, pdf1, type='l', xlab='x', ylab='f(x)', main='CDF of N(0,1), N(2,2^2) and N(-1,0.5^2)')

pdf2 <- pnorm(xvals, mean=2, sd=sqrt(2))
pdf3 <- pnorm(xvals, mean=-1, sd=sqrt(0.5))

lines(xvals, pdf2, col = 'red')
lines(xvals, pdf3, col = 'blue')
```

Resulting plot:

[image]